# Track DNN logins using Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am new to using Google Analytics, I was looking for a way to track our website's login information like count of logins, last login, when, who. Is there a way to capture those data to google analytics. I actually tried using custom variable -  but it is not the data I expected. By the way, I used the ga.js, here the sample code I used and the User Type is the only one captured.

```
        _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'UserID','1234567890',1]); 
        _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'Member Type','Premium',1]);
        _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'User Type','Member',2 ]);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 slots with (free) ga.js for custom variables. Since you write all variables to the same slot (second parameter of the call) the last call overwrites the previous ones. So this should rather be

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'UserID','1234567890',1]); 
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',2,'Member Type','Premium',1]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',3,'User Type','Member',2 ]);
```

where the second parameter is incremented for each var.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I updated the code and will wait for it to display in the report.  About the other concern, is there a way we can integrate DNN login information to Google Analytics??